Docker container running but can't get the browser working
I am using python3.10 and building a basic Q&A chatbot. I have built docker image using below dockerfile:
FROM python:3.10.14-bookworm
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app/requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["streamlit", "run", "app/app.py", "--server.port", "8080"]

I used docker build -t chatbotimg . command to build docker image and it got created as well, but when I tried to run it, it started like below:
Collecting usage statistics. To deactivate, set browser.gatherUsageStats to false.

You can now view your Streamlit app in your browser.

Local URL: http://localhost:8080
Network URL: http://172.17.0.1:8080
External URL: http://105.222.203.146:8080

But when I clicked on the link, the browser wasn't working, it gave an error (Safari browser): Safari Can't open the page "localhost:8080" because safari Can't connect to the server "localhost". Can someone please help me resolving this issue?

How are you running the container?  Do you have a docker run -p option?  Do you need to configure the application to listen on 0.0.0.0 and not just the container-private localhost?

@DavidMaze, I am new to docker, I am just trying to build a basic application, yes, I do have docker run -p option, I ran it using "docker run chatbotimg" command. For now I am just checking it on localhost.

"localhost" or 127.0.0.1 is not the same for your host and the container. Every container has its own loopback interface which is separate from all others. You're looking on your host's loopback interface but the container is serving on its own, so this can't work.

You need to map ports on your computer to the container, try this:
docker build -t chatbotimg .
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080 chatbotimg 


Awesome, thanks a lot for your help. It works now.

Glad to hear it, good luck!

How are you running the container? You need to bind port 8080 of your container to port 8080 of your host machine. You should be able to do this by running:
docker run -p 8080:8080 chatbotimg


Awesome, thanks a lot for your help. It works now.
